# UIView setNeedsDisplay doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiview, setneedsdisplay

Simple code is here:

Custom MyButton.h

```
@interface PaiLifeReadingListButton : UIButton
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *logoImageView;
@end
```

Custom MyButton.m

```
@implementation PaiLifeReadingListButton
@synthesize logoImageView = _logoImageView;
-(id)init
{
    _logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33.0, 20.0, 80.0, 80.0)];
    [_logoImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic"]];
    [self addSubview: _logoImageView];
}  
@end
```

Custom MyView.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Mybutton *mybutton;
```

Custom MyView.m:

```
-(id) init
{
    myButton = [[MyButton alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:myButton];
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
@synthesize myView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myView = [[Myview alloc] init];
    [myView.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    self.view = myView;
}
-(void)pressed : (MyButton *)button
{
    UIImageView *newImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"other-pic"] highlightedImage:nil];
    myView.myButton.logImageView = newImageView;
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; //----this does not work
}
```

When I press the button, the imageview does not change. How can I fix this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Set the newImageView.frame = logImageView.frame.Don't need to call setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: What is `button` and where did you add `myButton` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Sorry for that, I made a mistake and I change the code.

Comment: @dhcdht No, it does not work for me.

Comment: also that's not the best way to override the initializer and in this case you should override the designated one (-initWithFrame:)

Comment: @Moxy Thank you, just a simple code here.

Comment: Add some more clear code. And give logs on the `pressed:` method to see if myButton or logImageView or myView is nil.

Answer (score 1):

First thing , you don't need `setNeedsDisplay` here. `setNeedsDisplay` is used for redrawing the view (it internally calls the `drawRect:` method of the view if required) which is not what you want.

Second, you have given the class of your button as `MyButton`,but in the actual .h and .m files, it is given as `@interface PaiLifeReadingListButton` and `@implementation PaiLifeReadingListButton` respectively.

Another thing, the view and button is not initialized with a frame. But I assume you have done that already, since your only problem is the image view not changing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code in pressed method you should change views in the hierarchy, but you change only the object member. You can do something like

```
myView.myButton.logImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"other-pic"];
```